# UNION ALL and NOT IN together

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, union

SQL Server - I have 3 simple tables (Fname, Lname and Exceptions) with one column each called Name. I want my end result to look like: (Everybody in Fname + Everybody in LName) - (Everybody in Exceptions).

FName:

```
Name
A
B
```

LName:

```
Name
Y
Z
```

Exceptions:

```
Name
A
Z
```

Expected Query Result Set:

```
B
Y
```

Current SQL Query:

```
Select Name from Fname
UNION ALL
Select Name from Lname
WHERE Name NOT IN
(Select Name from Exceptions)
```

The SQL query only works on removing data which appears in LName but not in Fname. Can somebody please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parts of a `UNION` are handled as separate queries, so you can group them in a subquery:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM (Select Name from Fname
      UNION ALL
      Select Name from Lname)sub
WHERE Name NOT IN (Select Name from Exceptions)
```

You can keep that as `UNION ALL` if you don't care about duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

You need a subquery, i prefer `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT X.name 
FROM   (SELECT name 
        FROM   fname 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT name 
        FROM   lname) X 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   exceptions E 
                   WHERE  x.name = E.name)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dfebd/7/0)

[Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

However, `NOT IN` works the same way:

```
SELECT X.name 
FROM   (SELECT name 
        FROM   fname 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT name 
        FROM   lname) X 
WHERE  X.name NOT IN (SELECT name 
                      FROM   exceptions)
```

Answer (score 5):

If your RBBMS have except (SQL Server or PostgreSQL have, don't know about MySQL)

```
select Name from FName
union all
select Name from LName
except
select Name from Exceptions
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dfebd/8)

Comment: MySQL does not support `EXCEPT`.

Comment: @HaralanDobrev OP use SQL Server

Comment: More proof that postgreSQL rocks. Cheers!